# Can I make an android game using OPEN GL ES with c language?

Tags: c, opengl-es

I saw that most OPEN GL ES resources are written in java. And i don't know java. Can I make an android game using OPEN GL ES with c language? Is this possible? If possible, will I have trouble in compiling and similar situations?

Note:I want to make a 2d game for android.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Use Android NDK - native developer kit for C/C++ developers: https://developer.android.com/ndk

> The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you implement parts of your app in native code, using languages such as C and C++. For certain types of apps, this can help you reuse code libraries written in those languages.

Example:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na

The native-activity sample resides under the NDK samples root, in folder native-activity. It is a very simple example of a purely native application, with no Java source code. In the absence of any Java source, the Java compiler still creates an executable stub for the virtual machine to run. The stub serves as a wrapper for the actual, native program, which is located in the .so file.